# Como mudar conteudo de um select a partir de outro select

Tags: php, html

Como consigo colocar um botão relacionado com o outro?

Exemplo:

```
<span class="IWLABEL10CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Distrito</span>
<select name="PAIS" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
 <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
 <option value="Portugal">PORTUGAL</option>
<option value="Brasil">BRASIL</option>
<option value="Espanha">ESPANHA</option>
</select>
```

e depois tenho outra opção que é os Concelhos.

```
<span class="IWLABEL7CSS" id="IWLABEL7">Concelho</span>
<select name="CIDADE" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOCONCCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
 <option value="Indiferente">Indiferente</option>
     <option value="Lisboa">Lisboa</option>
     <option value="Porto">Porto</option>
     <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
     <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
     <option value="Brasilia">Brasilia</option>
     <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
```

Escolho ESPANHA na primeira opção PAIS e quero que apareça apenas Nas cidades BARCELONA, MADRID, etc.

Comment: Sera necessária o uso do javascript/jQuery

Comment: Com jQuery você consegue fazer isso.

Comment: e como se chama essa função em javascript?

Comment: Você precisaria de um arquivo json com todas os países e com cidades. e depois quando você seleciona-se o país você pegaria o selecionado e fazia a busca dentro do json para trazer as cidades referente ao país, mas acredito que seria grande demais para ser respondido aqui.. mas vou ver o que consigo pra você... aguarde...

Comment: E você já tem o código todo na página ou vai buscar via Ajax?

Comment: Tenho tudo na mesma página.

Comment: Ok. Poste o código que tem e a resposta fica bem fácil.

Comment: Tenho assim. os dois botões de opção.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sua pergunta é incompleta. Posso ajudar mais a explicar o que é preciso numa pergunta, ou próximas perguntas, para ser clara para quem quer ajudar. [No Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) há de certeza uma pergunta referência mas não a encontro agora.

Ainda assim, fica aqui uma sugestão. Neste código em baixo mudei o seu ID duplicado para o segundo select. ID's têm de ser únicos, e já agora dá jeito ter um ID nesse select.

Adicionei um campo `data-pais=""` nas suas options. Assim, se todas estiverem no mesmo select dá para as mostrar/esconder.

```
<option data-pais="Portugal" value="Lisboa">Lisboa</option>
<option data-pais="Portugal" value="Porto">Porto</option>
<option data-pais="Espanha" value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
```

Acrescentei também CSS, aqui pode optar por retirar este código completamente se quiser que todas as opções estejam disponíveis.

```
#COMBOCID option{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('select[name="PAIS"]').on('change', function(){
    var pais = this.value;
    $('select[name="CIDADE"] option').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.data('pais') == pais) $this.show();
        else $this.hide();
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/XH42p/

Comment: @user3253195, aqui fica uma nova versão: __http://jsfiddle.net/XH42p/__

Answer (score -2):

Acho que daria pra você usar esse script

```
<select name="odin" id="odin" onchange="turnTo(this)">
        <option value="Vaca">Vaca</option>
        <option value="Boi">Boi</option>
        <option value="Ovelha">Ovelha</option>
    </select>
    <select name="thor" id="thor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function turnTo(source){
            var slc = document.getElementById(source.id);
            var opcaoTexto = slc.options[slc.selectedIndex].text;
            var opcaoValor = slc.options[slc.selectedIndex].value;
            console.log(opcaoValor + "\n" + opcaoTexto);

            var scdSelect = document.getElementById('thor');
            var vlOption = scdSelect.options[scdSelect.selectedIndex].value = opcaoValor;
            var vlTextOption = scdSelect.options[scdSelect.selectedIndex].text = opcaoValor;
            console.log(vlOption + "\n" + vlTextOption);
        }        
    </script>
```