# Option ex: selecione estado | selecione cidade

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

Tenho 3 Options, e conforme cada um fosse selecionado ele traria o resultado o próximo option.

Ex: Option 1 Selecione o estado | Option 2 selecione a cidade

Então assim quando selecionado o option estado ele trazer as cidades existentes no próximo.

Tem como fazer isso só com jquery ou tem que ser com banco de dados mesmo, pois a plataforma e-commerce que uso não tem suporte a banco de dados para eu subir.

Comment: Tem como fazer até com JS puro. Você pode subir por exemplo arquivos JSON com os estados e carregar via AJAX. Pode por todas as combinações num .js só tambem, se preferir.

Comment: possível duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10758/129

Comment: Eu já havia procurado mas não tinha encontrado a mesma questão que a minha.