# Listar dados em um drop down relacionados com o resultado de outro drop down

Tags: php, javascript

Ola pessoal Não tenho ideia de como proceder nesse caso

Resumindo preciso em 2º dropdown liste dados relacionado com o resultado do primeiro
No caso do script a baixo ele mostrar as empresas e os usuários pertencentes a elas

1º Select: Listar empresas e pega o Id do selecionado

```
<select  name="empresa"  style="width: 160px;" required>
$sql = "SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE id_transfer = '$id_transfer'";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
$id_empresa = $linha["id_empresa"];
$nome = $linha["nome_fan"];
<option value="<?echo $id?>"><?echo $nome?></option>   
<?}?>
</select>
```

2º Select: Capitura o ID do 1º Select e mostrar os resultados pertencentes a eles

```
<select  name="user_soli" style="width: 160px;" required >
<option value=""></option>   
<?      
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user = '$id_empresa'";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
$id = $linha["id_empresa"];
$nome = $linha["nome_fan"];
?>
<option value="<?echo $id?>"><?echo $nome?></option>   
<?}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Queres dizer que quando carregas a página um dos selects está preenchido e queres que o outro seja preenchido após o primeiro ter sido selecionado? sabes como usar ajax?

Comment: Sim ao selecionar o  empresa x  logo ja mostrar todos os usuarios dela no segundo dropdown.

Comment: sabes o que é e como usar ajax?

Comment: Não Sei usar ajax só sei PHP

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10766/129 entretanto

Comment: Seria tipo dois selects um de estado e o outro em branco. Qnd escolher o estado no outro aparece as cidades

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser complicado o que você quer, porém é mais simples do que imagina.

Você terá que primeiro separar o arquivo PHP usado para fazer a consulta na base de dados.

Suponhamos que você possui um arquivo com a consulta dos usuários cujo o nome seja getUsuarios.php.

Iremos passar um valor via parâmetro em javascript, para facilitar o exemplo irei explicar com a biblioteca do jQuery.

Basta montar uma consulta via $get ou $post, toda vez que for realizado um “change” no select principal, uma consulta será realizada remotamente e o valor retornará para option do segundo select.

## JavaScript (Exemplo)

```
$('.PrimeiroSelectClass').on('change', function() {

   $.get( "getUsuarios.php", { id: this.value }).done(function( data ) {
     $( ".result" ).html( data );
     Console.log( "Resultado carregado" );
   });

});
```

## PHP

Basta pegar o valor passado por parâmetro usando $_GET ou $_POST, realize a consulta com o código que você possui e retorne os valores. Nesse exemplo, o retorno será em HTML

Você pode obter mais informações neste link. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-get.htm

Recomendo que retorne os valores via JSON ou XML. Porém via HTML é uma solução ágil para seu caso e funcional.

Recomendo que leia também:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- https://api.jquery.com/change/