# Como popular um combobox em tempo de execução

Tags: javascript, html5, combobox, html-select

Como popular um **combobox** **(Select)** ao clicar em outro combobox, por exemplo eu tenho um combobox com 3 opções ao selecionar uma opção ele recarrega o outro com as opcoes referentes ao selecionado, alguém saberia como fazer isso usando **javascript**?

Achei varios exemplos antes de publicar a pergunta mas nenhum me atendei, então o que eu gostaria de fazer é identico o código abaixo o problema é que quando eu inicializo a pagina ele exibe 3 opções de cidades, no caso Macae aparece duas vezes até que o usuário selecione uma opção, e quando eu vou enviar os dados e como o exemplo funciona com a filtragem através do Value ele não envia as informações que eu gostaria de enviar que seria o conteúdo importante para o usuário, segue o código abaixo.

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function(){
        var concelhos = $('select[name="cmbcidade"] option');
        $('select[name="cmbopcao"]').on('change', function () {
            var Cmbopcao = this.value;
            var novoSelect = concelhos.filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('distrito') == Cmbopcao;
            });
            $('select[name="cmbcidade"]').html(novoSelect);
        });
        });//]]> 
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Selecione a seguinte opção: 
<select name="cmbopcao" size="1" width="180" class="COMBODISTCSS" id="COMBOFAB" tabindex="1">
    <option value="dois">Escritório Mobiliado</option>
    <option value="dois">Escritório Virtual</option>
    <option value="dois">Escritório Eventual</option>
    <option value="um">Escritório de Treinamento</option>
    <option value="dois">Escritório de Reunião</option>
    <option value="dois">Video Conferencia</option>
</select></p>

<p>Selecione a cidade:
<select name="cmbcidade" size="1" width="195" class="COMBOCONCCSS" id="COMBOCID" tabindex="1">
    <option data-distrito="dois" value="Macae">Macae</option>
    <option data-distrito="dois" value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option data-distrito="um" value="Macae">Macae</option>
</select></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar o código que você fez até agora?

Comment: Dá para fazer com ajax.

Comment: Olha essa [**pergunta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10758/como-mudar-conteudo-de-um-select-a-partir-de-outro-select), possível duplicada.

Comment: Bruno, dê mais detalhes sobre o seu problema. De onde vem os dados do primeiro select? como está o seu código?

Comment: Bruno, creio que o teu problema tem solução na resposta no link de duplicata. Se não fôr diz-me aqui que reabro e damos mais esclarecimentos.

Comment: Publiquei o código