# Zerar valor de um Select baseado em um option

Tags: javascript, html

Como poderia fazer para zerar um valor de um select baseado no option de outro select, por exemplo tenho essas duas caixas de seleção, quando a opção "A vista" for marcada gostaria de zerar o valor de parcelas no outro select, é possível fazer isso? Queria fazer isso porque estou passando o valor para o PHP e jogando em um modelo HTML para gerar um PDF, porém sempre está marcado o valor "2x" no segundo select.

```
<select name="f_taskop">
  <option value="À vista">À vista</option>
  <option value="Parcelado">Parcelado</option>
</select>

<select id="n-parcelas" name="f_parce">
  <option value="2">2x</option>
  <option value="3">3x</option>
  <option value="4">4x</option>
</select>
```

Comment: O que queres dizer com `zerar o valor de parcelas`? queres remover as opções ou mudar os valores das opções disponíveis?

Comment: Queria mudar o valor para 0 quando tiver selecionado o "a vista" no primeiro select.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mudar conteudo de um select a partir de outro select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10758/como-mudar-conteudo-de-um-select-a-partir-de-outro-select)

Comment: @HenriqueBretone mas não há nenhuma opção com o valor `0`.

Comment: Então no segundo select é preciso ter uma opção com o valor 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criei uma `<option>` com valor zero no `select` de parcelas em caso da forma de pagamento ser à vista, criei uma `classe` para simular um `readonly` no `select` de parcelas assim o usuário perceberá que as parcelas só estão disponíveis para forma de pagamento parcelada.

Sempre que a forma de pagamento for alterada verifico qual é seu novo valor para "habilitar as parcelas/ desabilitar e zerar as parcelas"

```js
function habilitaParcelas(f_taskop){
  var formaPagamento = f_taskop.value;
  var parcelas = document.getElementById('n-parcelas');
  if(formaPagamento == 'Parcelado'){
    parcelas.classList.remove("selectReadonly");
  }else{
    parcelas.value = "0";
    parcelas.classList.add("selectReadonly");
  }
}
```

```css
.selectReadonly {
    background: #eee; 
    pointer-events: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="f_taskop">Forma de pagamento: </label>
  <select name="f_taskop" id="f_taskop" onchange="habilitaParcelas(this)">
    <option value="À vista">À vista</option>
    <option value="Parcelado">Parcelado</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="f_taskop">Parcelas</label>
  <select id="n-parcelas" name="f_parce" class="selectReadonly" tabindex="-1">    
    <option value="0">Seleção disponível para pagamentos parcelados</option>
    <option value="2">2x</option>
    <option value="3">3x</option>
    <option value="4">4x</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solução usando `addEventListener` e `window.onload` (criando `<option>` dinamicamente no `select` das parcelas):

```js
pri_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
seg_select = document.getElementById("n-parcelas");

function checaSelect(){
 if(pri_select.value == "À vista"){
  seg_select.setAttribute("style","pointer-events: none;touch-action: none;background: #eee;");
  opt_1x = document.createElement("option");
  opt1x_txt = document.createTextNode("1x");
  opt_1x.appendChild(opt1x_txt);
  opt_1x.setAttribute("value","0");
  seg_select.insertBefore(opt_1x,seg_select.getElementsByTagName("option")[0])
  seg_select.selectedIndex = 0;
 }else{
  seg_select.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].outerHTML = "";
  seg_select.setAttribute("style","");
 }
}

pri_select.addEventListener("change", checaSelect);
window.onload = checaSelect();
```

```html
<select name="f_taskop">
  <option value="À vista">À vista</option>
  <option value="Parcelado">Parcelado</option>
</select>

<select id="n-parcelas" name="f_parce">
  <option value="2">2x</option>
  <option value="3">3x</option>
  <option value="4">4x</option>
</select>
```